# Associating Screens with GridLayout classes in kivy

Tags: python, kivy

I've created a ScreenManager, and created several Screen instances for that ScreenManager.

I'd like each Screen to display a GridLayout class. For example, let's say you have:

```
class MainScreen(Screen):
   ...

class MainLayout(GridLayout):
   ...
```

When MainScreen is the active screen, I'd like MainLayout to be shown.

Is there a way to do this purely in python (i.e. without markup)? Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a way to do this purely in python (i.e. without markup)? Thank you.

You never *need* to use kivy language (I assume that's what you mean by markup), though it's highly recommended where possible because it makes lots of stuff easier.

Nonetheless, to actually answer your question, all you have to do is add your gridlayout widget to your screen widget, something like

```
mainscreen = MainScreen()
mainlayout = MainLayout()
mainscreen.add_widget(mainlayout)
```

Then when you set the current screen in your screenmanager to be mainscreen, you should see the GridLayout.

Edit: In case it's unclear, this is in general the way you add widgets to other widgets. When you see an example in kv language like

```
<MyScreen>:
     GridLayout:
         ...
```

...ultimately that gets translated to something much like the above example code - an instance of MyScreen is created and a GridLayout is added to it with add_widget.