# Adding custom view classes to Screen Manager

Tags: python, kivy

I'm simply trying to make some example code I found which dynamically adds widgets to a view incorporate with a Screen Manager, and I cannot get it to work.

I found this example [Associating Screens with GridLayout classes in kivy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18937360/associating-screens-with-gridlayout-classes-in-kivy?rq=1) and as far as I know I've implemented the strategy defined there, but I keep getting  kivy.uix.screenmanager.ScreenManagerException: ScreenManager accepts only Screen widget.

EDIT: Here's my updated code. now getting error:  AttributeError: MainScreen instance has no attribute 'add_widget'

```
from kivy.uix.modalview import ModalView
from kivy.uix.listview import ListView
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.app import App
import citylists

from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen, FadeTransition

#using 'sla'...whatever that means...
Builder.load_string("""
#:import ListItemButton kivy.uix.listview
#:import sla kivy.adapters.listadapter

<ListViewModal>:
    ListView:
        size_hint: .8, .8
        adapter:
            sla.ListAdapter(
            data=["Item #{0}".format(i) for i in range(100)],
            cls=ListItemButton.ListItemButton)
""")

class ListViewModal(ModalView):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(ListViewModal, self).__init__(**kwargs)


class MainView(Screen):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        kwargs['cols'] = 1
        super(MainView, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        listview_modal = ListViewModal()

        self.add_widget(listview_modal)

class MainScreen():
    pass

mainscreen=MainScreen()
mainlayout = MainView()
mainscreen.add_widget(mainlayout)

class CARApp(App):
    screen_manager = None

    def build(self):
        self.screen_manager = ScreenManager()
        self.screen_manager.add_widget(mainscreen)


if __name__ == '__main__':
     CARApp().run()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> self.screen_manager.add_widget(MainScreen)

You're passing the actual class MainScreen, but you need to add an *instance* of the class, i.e. `MainScreen()`.

Edit, although looking more at your code, you probably want to add the instance you have already created, which is `mainscreen`. It might also be neater to move this widget creation into the build method, since that's where it's actually needed.

Comment: I then get  AttributeError: MainScreen instance has no attribute 'add_widget'
when I add the instance to the Screen Manager self.screen_manager.add_widget(mainscreen)

Comment: It's not clear what's wrong, could you post the full code with your changes?

Comment: Code updated. As far as I know, I'm adding the instance instead of the class, but it complains that the Screen has no 'add_widget' attribute

Comment: Oh, I see, it's because it doesn't - you declared it as `class MainScreen():` but you presumably meant to inherit from Screen with `class MainScreen(Screen):`