# Python kivy two GridLayouts and Screen Menager

Tags: python, python-2.7, kivy

I have two apps in kivy. 
Both were based on GridLayout
I found a similar problem but I do not understand: [Associating Screens with GridLayout classes in kivy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18937360/associating-screens-with-gridlayout-classes-in-kivy?rq=1)

In **.py**:

```
import kivy
kivy.require("1.9.0")
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout

class FirstScreen(GridLayout):
    #some methods
class SecondScreen(GridLayout):
    #some methods
```

In **.kv**

```
<FirstScreen>:
    id: sterowanie_serv
    display: entry
    rows: 10
    padding: 10
    spacing: 10
    BoxLayout:
        spacing: 20
        CustButton:
            text:'1'
            on_press: do method from second screen class
        CustButton:
            text:'x'
            on_press: do method from second screen class
        CustButton:
            text:'go to Second screen'
            on_press: root.manager.current = 'SecondScreen'

<SecondScreen>:
    id: Przemo
    display: entry
    rows: 5
    padding: 10
    spacing: 10
    BoxLayout:
        spacing: 20
        CustButton:
            text:'1'
            on_press: do method from second screen class
        CustButton:
            text:'x2'
            on_press: do method from second screen class
        CustButton:
            text:'go to First screen'
            on_press: root.manager.current = 'SecondScreen'
```

How to use the screen manager to first display *First Screen* and click on the button *Second Screen* was displayed?

In buttom will be :

```
on_press: 
    root.manager.current = 'SecondScreen'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ScreenManager` accepts only `Screen` widgets. `FirstScreen` and `SecondScreen` have to be `Screen` instances, they can not be `GridLayouts`. Inside `FirstScreen` and `SecondScreen` is where you should create the GridLayouts.

On the other hand, `ScreenManager.current` attribute is the **name** of the screen currently shown. You need to set **name** attribute in your windows.

Example based on your code:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen

kv_text = """\
#:import WipeTransition kivy.uix.screenmanager.WipeTransition
<MainScreen>:
    transition: WipeTransition()
    id: sm
    FirstScreen:
    SecondScreen:

<FirstScreen>:
    name: "first_screen"
    GridLayout:
        id: sterowanie_serv
        rows: 10
        padding: 10
        spacing: 10
        BoxLayout:
            spacing: 20
            Button:
                text:'1'
                on_press: print(app.root)
            Button:
                text:'x'
                on_press: print('Button X')
            Button:
                text:'go to Second screen'
                on_press: app.root.current = 'second_screen'

<SecondScreen>:
    name: "second_screen"
    GridLayout:
        id: Przemo
        rows: 5
        padding: 10
        spacing: 10
        BoxLayout:
            spacing: 20
            Button:
                text:'1'
                on_press: print('Button 1')
            Button:
                text:'x2'
                on_press: print('Button X2')
            Button:
                text:'go to First screen'
                on_press: app.root.current = 'first_screen'
"""

class MainScreen(ScreenManager):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainScreen, self).__init__()

class FirstScreen(Screen):
    #some methods
    pass

class SecondScreen(Screen):
    #some methods
    pass

class MyKivyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MainScreen()

def main():
    Builder.load_string(kv_text)
    app = MyKivyApp()
    app.run()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Running example:

[image]

Comment: In button / sliders how do i reference methods?
I have all the class in control_serv.py file.
In kv I have in slider
Value: control_serv.get_val_3 () but I see
AttributeError: 'GridLayout' object has no attribute 'get_val_3'